# Send file data to file input element using JQuery & AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use a JQuery library for cropping images , after click on crop button, Cropped image (result) is send back to HTML page via AJAX as "file data", Something like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIwAAA
CMCAYAAACuwEE+AAAgAElEQVR4nOy8d7hdVZ3/z/xmfH4z83y...
```

I want to sent this result to server as normal image file, but i don't know how to "attach" data to `<input type="file" name="image" id="ajaxresult" hidden>` .

I tried `$("#ajaxresult").value(result);` , but no luck. server says its `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var formData = new FormData($('#formid')[0]);
  formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
  $.ajax({
    url: path,
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS (requires jQuery 1.6+)
    processData: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS
    success:function(){

    }
  });
```

Comment: OK I made changes on `ajax` part as you mentioned, but still how to handle `success` result and send to input element?

Comment: @fredi you want assign the base64 encode  data to #ajaxresult file filed you will use it this                                                                                                    
 var image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...';
document.body.appendChild(image);

Answer (score 0):

first `$data_one = explode(',',$var);` add add after used 
`base64_decode($data_one)` used and try..